# Graphically display my all Android Databases like phpmyadmin

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to view all of my databases graphically, just like we see in "PHPMYADMIN" , SQLYOG etc where we can manage our database create and drop it.. is this possible in Android?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since Android only supports server-less database SQLite for persistent storage, there's no implementation of phpMyAdmin or SQLYOG. However, you can use an app like SQLite Debugger by which you can achieve the aforementioned tasks.

Link : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=oliver.ehrenmueller.dbadmin&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9saXZlci5laHJlbm11ZWxsZXIuZGJhZG1pbiJd

Note : Root permissions required