# Using database in phonegap applications or not?

Tags: android, database, cordova

I'm new to PhoneGap, I'm making an application, it has like 500 words with definition of each word.

I have web developing background, in web developing, we create a database, and work with it, no matter the website is visited or not, data is there.

But in PhoneGap, it likes that we make a database every time that the application ran, and drop the table if it exist next time ( i dont know if i understood it right ).

So, if it's like that, it doesnt make any sense for me to use database at all !!

I want to know is there a way, that when user install the app on the phone, Data transfer automaticly, and it just be there when we need it ? ( not creating the table with the entries every time we need it ! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you don't have to create the DB at each app start and drop everything when you close the app. You can even version your DB. Here's a brief example:

```
db = window.openDatabase("mydbname", "",
  "App Name", <size_in_bytes>);
console.log("version is: " + db.version);
if (db.version == "") {
  // EMPTY STRING -> VERY FIRST ACCESS -> CREATE THE DB!
  db.changeVersion("", "1", createDB, 
      function(error) {
        console.log("ERROR DB from empty: " + JSON.stringify(error))
      },
      function() {
        console.log("version 1, done!");
      }
  );
} else {
  // We have the DB!
  [...]
}
```

And you put the `CREATE` stuff and eventually `INSERT` stuff in the `createDB` function.

Everything according to the API:

`window.openDatabase(name, version, display_name, size);`

Comment: Thanks for help, i have one follow up question, in MySQL, we have somthing called PHPMyAdmin to have control over database or in windows we have microsoft SQL server, what do we have in android for this purpose ? and is it the database available for users ? can they access to database, see the data or change them ?

Comment: Glade the answer helped you. For your second question I think that you can find some similar questions on SO, like the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564140/graphically-display-my-all-android-databases-like-phpmyadmin , that should answer your question.

Comment: that's a little inconvenient, doesn't it ? anyway, just another question, seems like you have experience in this field, and i need that, does it make sense to make like 4 tables with foreign keys and join them together when needed, or it push too much pressure to app ?

Comment: This is an hard question, I'm sorry but I cannot answer. It depends on too many factors, the amount of data, the type of queries, the type of data, etc. Anyway, the general rules for a good DB design hold even for the mobile environment, obviously